# How to create a multi-model, multi-page form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many

I am a newbie trying to learn Ruby on Rails.  I am trying to learn how to work with the has_many association.  I have a blog that I want to be able to add comments to. I am able to put an add comments form in a post page but i want to also learn how to add comments by going to a new page with an "add comments form".

However, I am not able to pass the necessary information about what post a comment belongs to.  I am not sure if it is a problem with my form or the comments_controller.

posts_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new  
  end
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

comment form

```
    <h1>Add a new comment</h1>
    <%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :comments
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to have the post id inside your comments page.

Do something like this:

When you are redirecting to the comments controller, pass the post id and get it from comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post_id = params[:id] 
    @comment = Comment.new  
  end
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

And in your comments/new.erb view, add the post id as a hidden param

```
<h1>Add a new comment</h1>
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %><%= f.text_field :post_id, @post_id  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am still stuck.  I understand that i need to pass the post_id to the comments controller but I am still unable to save a comment with proper post_id.  The hidden param in the view seems to break it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @monz, I have created a very simple blog app to demonstrate your solution, I could e-mail it if i have you mail